# Significant Inversions in an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, divide

I'm working on a homework problem to find the number of significant inversions in an array of integers. "Significant inversion" is defined as follows:

> A significant inversion in a permutation *[a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>]* is one in which *a<sub>i</sub> > 2 a<sub>j</sub>* for some *i < j*. so for example *a = [4,5,2,1,3]* has exactly 3 significant inversions, since for this permutation *a<sub>0</sub> > 2 a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>>2 a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>1</sub> > 2 a<sub>3</sub>*.

The solution needs to have *O(n log n)* complexity. This requires the use of a divide and conquer approach. I chose to implement the solution based off of merge sort.

I understand the splitting operation as given here:

```
def countInversions(list):
    if(len(list) <= 1):
        return list, 0
    else:
        mid = int(len(list)/2)
        left, a = countInversions(list[:mid])
        right, b = countInversions(list[mid:])
        result, c = mergeAndCount(left, right)
        return result, (a + b + c)
```

However I'm having trouble with the merge and count method. Specifically counting the number of significant inversions. I adapted my code from counting the normal number of inversions.

```
def mergeAndCount(left, right):
    result = []
    count = 0
    i,j = 0,0
    while(i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if(left[i] > 2*right[j]):
            count += 1
        if(left[i] < right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    while(left[i:] or right[j:]):
        if(left[i:]):
            if(left[i] > 2*right[j-1]):
                count += 1
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        if(right[j:]):
            if(left[i-1] > 2*right[j]):
                count += 1
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    return result, count
```

So `print(countInversions([4,5,2,1,3]))` should return 3. However, it returns 1.

I'm looking for some guidance on my merge and count method.

---

The final implementation:

```
def countInversions(list):
    if(len(list) <= 1):
        return list, 0
    else:
        mid = int(len(list)/2)
        left, a = countInversions(list[:mid])
        right, b = countInversions(list[mid:])
        result, c = mergeAndCount(left, right)
        return result, (a + b + c)

def mergeAndCount(left, right):
    result = []
    count = 0
    i,j = 0,0

    while(i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if(left[i] > 2*right[j]):
            count += len(left)-i
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1

    i,j = 0,0
    while(i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if(left[i] < right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    result.extend(left[i:])
    result.extend(right[j:])
    return result, count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there, but there are two issues:

1. When you have found `left[i] > 2*right[i]` you are meant to conclude that all of the values in `left[i:]` are greater than `2*right[i]` and so you should increment your count by `len(left(i:])` which is the same as len(left)-i.  (You are just adding 1 on which is why your values are too low.)
2. You need to split your merge pass into two stages, one to count the significant inversions, and one to produce a sorted output array.  (In a normal inversion count, these two would move i and j at the same points so can be combined, but that is not true for your case.)

Fixed code:

```
def mergeAndCount(left, right):
    result = []
    count = 0
    i,j = 0,0

    while(i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if(left[i] > 2*right[j]):
            count += len(left)-i
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1

    i,j = 0,0                
    while(i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if(left[i] < right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    while(left[i:] or right[j:]):
        if(left[i:]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        if(right[j:]):
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    return result, count
```

Comment: Could this be sped up slightly by comparing left-most to right-most, i.e. start j at len(right), and do j--, such that if a left[i] is a significant inversion of right[j], not only will all left[i:] also be inversions, but they will be inversions of all right[:j]. It might be ugly to implement, just curious.